# Creating Grid of images or custom buttons that are clickable

Tags: android

So I have been trying to use a canvas with bitmaps to create a grid of clickable images for a game. It is made to be a 19 x 19 board and this would be made of clickable images so that when you click a image it changes to a new image. I have tried doing this and I get the grid of images but I can not figure out a way to make them clickable. I would show code but there is nothing to show really. its just a basic custom view. Maybe I am doing this all wrong but I have seen a way that is somewhat similar that works but it does not use custom images. I can add a onTouchListener and then I get a response back but it still does not fulfill what I am trying to accomplish. I guess I need to create buttons inside of my custom view but I need the buttons to be customized by images and I cant figure out how I would go about doing that. That is where the issue lies, If there is a way to create a custom View of a grid of customizable buttons. How would I go about doing that? Sorry if this question seems.... messy but I have been working at this for awhile now and am getting pretty confused and lost. Any help is appreciated at this point.

Comment: This is just a suggestion but so can use weighting in your layout, I would suggest using 20x20 (5%x5%) or 16x16(6.25%x6025%).  When you get numbers with long running decimals as your left positions, your layout can get difficult to manage to make it equal distance around.

Comment: The game that I am making requires a odd number as there needs to be a center. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I think so. Not sure but if you use a grid view with image views on them you can do what you want to accomplish. For more in formation, check here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a [GridFragment](https://github.com/Tombarr/GridFragment) and just implement the onGridItemClick method to handle the clicks. It is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a gridview with buttons with custom background images I would go about it something like this.

I would store all my drawables in an int array

```
int[] imageResource = new int[] {R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon2, R.drawable.icon3};
```

Set your gridView with the adapter shown below and pass your drawables stored in an array

```
yourGridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(imageResource));
```

Now for the actual inner class Adapter

```
//create your own custom adapter for your gridView
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    int[] gridImages;

    public GridAdapter(int images[]){
          gridImages = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

          LayoutInflater li = context.getLayoutInflater();
           if (convertView == null) {

               //here you inflate your xml containing a button.
               convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

           }
           //you reference the button contained in the inflated xml
           Button imageButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);

           //now you set the button with a drawable from your int array
           Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(gridImages[position);


          // Now simply add your onClickListener and whatever else you need to achieve

          //return your view
          return convertView;
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return gridImages.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return gridImages[position];
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }
}
```

If done correctly, this should cycle through all your drawables referenced in the int array and place them on to buttons.

Comment: if I have only 1 image that needs to be displayed across a 19 x 19 board will this work? This seems to be more for images like a album but I am trying to make a gameboard view. Using a custom view as I stated above is much more preferable then using one similar to this because it gives me full control over everything in the view. Do you have any ideas for a custom view? Thanks for this code though it could be somewhat helpful for what I am doing.